# ECS task to VPC endpoint/NAT Gateway routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, nat, amazon-api-gateway, aws-fargate

we have an ECS task that makes Rest API calls of two types: /path1 and /path2 in a Private subnet. We route the requests to Internet Gateway through a NAT gateway present in a public subnet.

Flow: ECS task -> NAT Gateway -> Internet Gateway.

Now, we want to route the /path2 requests to a VPC endpoint that we will create.

ECS task -> path/1 -> NAT Gateway -> Internet Gateway.

ECS task -> path/2 -> vpc endpoint ->

How can we achieve this?